# SQL - JSON Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot figure out where I made a mistake, in all selections I search for one value and put it in a variable, then I try to bring everything to the Json form, what am I doing wrong?

```
    declare @edrpou nvarchar(max) = N'{"code":"26370496"}'
    declare @o_output nvarchar(max)

BEGIN

    declare @filiaName nvarchar(max)
    declare @edrpouCode nvarchar(max)
    declare @address nvarchar(max)
    declare @maincode int
    declare @mainName nvarchar(max)
    declare @mainAddress nvarchar(max)
    declare @createdOn datetime


    Select @edrpouCode = edrpou
    From openjson(@edrpou, '$')
    With 
    (
        edrpou nvarchar(64) '$.code'
    )
    Set @mainName = (
        Select [EDR].[Names_Name]
        from [dbo].[EDR] join [dbo].[EDRBranch]
        on @edrpouCode = EDRBranch.code AND
        [dbo].[EDRBranch].[Guid] = [dbo].[EDR].[Guid]
    )

    Set @maincode = (
        Select [EDR].[Code]
        from [dbo].[EDR] join [dbo].[EDRBranch]
        on @edrpouCode = EDRBranch.code AND
        [dbo].[EDRBranch].[Guid] = [dbo].[EDR].[Guid]
    )
    Set @mainAddress = (
        Select [EDRAddress].[address] from [EDRAddress] join [EDRBranch]
        on @edrpouCode = EDRBranch.code
        AND  [dbo].[EDRBranch].[Guid] = [EDRAddress].[Guid]
    )
    Set @filiaName = (
        Select [dbo].[EDRBranch].[Name]
        from [dbo].[EDRBranch] join [dbo].[EDR] 
        on  [dbo].[EDRBranch].[Code] = @edrpouCode AND 
            [dbo].[EDRBranch].[Guid] = [dbo].[EDR].[Guid]
        )
    Set @createdOn = (
        Select [dbo].[EDR].[createdOn]
        from [dbo].[EDRBranch] join [dbo].[EDR] 
        on  [dbo].[EDRBranch].[Code] = @edrpouCode AND 
            [dbo].[EDRBranch].[Guid] = [dbo].[EDR].[Guid]
        )
    Set @address = (
        Select Country, Zip, [dbo].[EDRAddress].[Address]
        from [dbo].[EDRBranch] join [dbo].[EDRAddress] 
        on  [dbo].[EDRBranch].Code = @edrpouCode
        where [dbo].[EDRBranch].[AddressGuid] = dbo.[EDRAddress].[Guid]
    )
```

Here I think that I have one value in each variable and I do Select and write to JSON

```
    Set @o_output = (  
    SELECT

        @filiaName  AS 'Name',
        @edrpouCode AS 'Code',
        @address As 'Address'
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    )

END
```

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: i'm Sorry MSSQL

Comment: Why don't you just use `top 1` for all the queries before putting into json and check if it is working or not ?

Comment: Could you show me an example, becouse I'm new to sql?

Comment: You can't have a subquery like this returning multiple columns: `set @address = ( select Country, Zip, Address from ...)`

Comment: I understood you, thanks